# TypeError: Argument 'element' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got None Type)

Tags: docx, docassemble

When I try to generate an interview with docx file in Docassemble it raises the error:

TypeError: Argument 'element' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got None Type)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in docx file. Create a new docx file in Windows, insert just one field in it to test. If it works, then you add the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually an open pull request to fix this bug in docxcompose, an upstream dependency of Docassemble. For a specific DOCX file, you should be able to fix it by opening the file in Word and then saving, as it appears to be an issue with very small errors that Word automatically fixes on save.

https://github.com/4teamwork/docxcompose/pull/58